# this creates msg, but whats the cmd command to send automatically

Tags: batch-file, cmd, lotus-notes

So I am using the answer from Sighn which works great in setting up the message and everything I need but i want to insert a new command that will automatically send the email in lotus notes instead of the user having to press the "send" button.

https://superuser.com/questions/759191/sending-an-email-with-lotus-notes-using-windows-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write the code in Lotusscript directly?
If the user is in Lotus Notes, just give them an action button or something to send the email.
If they are in another application, and your Domino server is web accessable, create a web service or an agent that you can call with Ajax.

You can use my mail class to make this easy for you:
http://blog.texasswede.com/lotusscript-mail-notification-class/

This is how you would create and send a mail using it:

```
Option Public
Option Declare
Use "Class.MailNotification"

Sub Initialize
 Dim mail As NotesMail
 ' *** Create a mail
 Set mail = New NotesMail()
 ' *** Set receipient and subject
 mail.MailTo = "texasswede@example.com"
 Call mail.AddMailTo("jane.doe@example.com")
 mail.Subject = "Please Read This"
 ' *** Set "fake" sender address
 mail.Principal = |"Do Not Reply" <noreply@example.com>|
 ' Create body
 Call mail.AppendText("Testing email...")
 Call mail.AppendNewLine(2)
 Call mail.Send()
End Sub
```

Comment: I wanted to just do something simple for an autosys job but this looks like this could work as well, i've heard about lotus script but I never tested it out that's why

Comment: can you look at my java code for this? it is very similar to your vba code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311053/how-to-bypass-lotus-notes-password-log-in-java-code